# Multiple ListBoxes and insert form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, cascade-filtering

I want to create multiple listboxes when you select the first it does a database query  which gets a list for the second list box and it carries on for the third and so on. Beside each list box is a form to insert an entry for that list is there an article or video on how to do this. Some ajax might be needed to do what I want Im not really sure what to do I can't find an article on this. does anyone have any links for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the functionality like what would be done in **[Cascading DropDownList](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)** except that your control is `ListBox`.

See samples and Ideas there, it could be helpful.

Comment: can you programatically create the dropdownlist from javascript.The list can go quite deep

Comment: You mean the ability to fill it with an Ajax call? See this http://easylistbox.com/demoRelatedAjax.aspx, http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/97/Cascading-DropDownLists-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET, http://forums.asp.net/p/1363647/2830556.aspx#2830556